# Same text tab for multiple signers

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible for two or more signers to share the same text tab, so that either of them can complete the tab, but if the first signer completes the tab the second signer can edit the entered value, and if the first signer didn't enter a value the second signer can?  I'm trying to do this with tabs positioned by anchor text, but at signing time the second signer sees an empty text entry block positioned on top of whatever the first signer entered, rather than seeing a text block filled with the previous entry.

Ideally, I'd like to make it so this is a required tab for the envelope as a whole, but optional for any individual signer -- that is, one of the signers has to fill this in, but we don't care which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property `textTab.Shared = true` so that all recipients can view and edit the tab value.

Documentation [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/create/#definitions--text)

---

### Making TextTab mandatory for a specific signer

`textTab.required = true`

Other signers can still edit the textTab if `shared=true`, but it will not be mandatory for other signers.

---

### Making TextTab Mandatory for all Signers

```
shared = true
requireAll = true
```

Comment: Thanks, CodingDawg.  I've been able to test the shared = true, and it works to allow the two signers to share the tab.  I haven't been able yet to test requireAll = true.  Does that allow the first signer to leave the tab empty, so that the second signer can fill it in?  The documentation isn't clear to me.

Comment: If `requireAll=true` then the first recipient will have to fill the text tab.  The next recipients can choose to modify the value, but cannot leave the value empty.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Do you happen to know if it's possible to set up a text tab so that either signer *may* fill it in, but one of the signers *must* fill it in?  So if the first signer fills it in, the second signer can ignore it, but if the first signer leaves it empty, the second signer has to fill it in?

Comment: Assign the tab to the second recipient. Set `required=true` and `shared=true` .. This way the first recipient can choose to leave the tab empty and second recipient has to enter a value.

Comment: I've discovered a problem with this approach, in my case -- It turns out I didn't give enough information.  We have three or four signers, of which only two should be party to this tab.  If I make it shared, all of the signers get to edit it, not just the two for whom it is relevant.  I have to think about how to accomplish this, but if you have any suggestions, I'd be happy to hear them.

Comment: Can you please post a new question so that more people can look at it and provide an answer.